# Changes in time picker should also changes the time input field

Tags: javascript

I've got this code to show the total minutes in an input field. I would like to have changes in it whenever a user picks a different time in the time picker and the time in the input field also changes. How would I get that goal? This is the code I used:

```js
const getSeconds = s => s.split(":").reduce((acc, curr) => acc * 60 + +curr, 0);
var seconds1 = getSeconds(document.getElementById("stime").value);
var seconds2 = getSeconds(document.getElementById("etime").value);

var res = Math.abs(seconds2 - seconds1);

var hours = Math.floor(res / 3600);
var minutes = Math.floor(res % 3600 / 60);
var seconds = res % 60;

document.getElementById("time").value = seconds;
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="stime" class="form-control" required name="stime" type="time" value="12:00" />
    <label for="stime">Start Time</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="etime" class="form-control" required name="etime" type="time" value="12:30" />
    <label for="etime">End Time</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="time" class="form-control" name="time" type="text" />
    <label for="time">Time</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how image looks like...

[image: This is the image on how it looks like..]

Comment: listen to a change event and on change; do the calculation?

Comment: Can you please share enough of your code that we can recreate the problem easily? Add the relevant HTML to your code snippet, that way people can provide an accurate, practicable and useful answer to your question (and it makes it easier for future visitors to understand and apply the answers).

Comment: @KarelG -- Yes, I'm not used to javascript but I think that's what it is.

Comment: You need to specify whether the start time needs to be updated or the end time when the input changes. It has caused ambiguity in your algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to move the calculation parts of your code into a function and call that function once the page is loaded and when any change is made to the inputs.

```js
const getSeconds = s => s.split(":").reduce((acc, curr) => acc * 60 + +curr, 0);
const twoDigit = s => s < 10 ? '0'+s : s;
const timeToMins = s => s.split(':')[0]*60 + +s.split(':')[1];

const formatTime = s => {
  let hours = Math.floor(s / 60);
  let minutes = Math.floor(s % 60);
  return `${twoDigit(hours)}:${twoDigit(minutes)}`
}

const updateInput = () => {
  let start = getSeconds(document.getElementById("stime").value);
  let end = getSeconds(document.getElementById("etime").value);
  let res = Math.abs(end - start);
  let diff = formatTime(res) 
  document.getElementById("time").value = diff;
}

const updateEnd = () => {
  let start = getSeconds(document.getElementById("stime").value);
  let diff = document.getElementById("time").value
  let end = formatTime(start+timeToMins(diff))
  document.getElementById("etime").value = end;
}

updateInput()
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="stime" onchange="updateInput()" class="form-control" required name="stime" type="time" value="12:00" />
    <label for="stime">Start Time</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="etime" onchange="updateInput()" class="form-control" required name="etime" type="time" value="12:30" />
    <label for="etime">End Time</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="time" onkeyup="updateEnd()" class="form-control" name="time" type="text" />
    <label for="time">Time Difference</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the codes I have so far for this.

```js
const getSeconds = s => s.split(":").reduce((acc, curr) => acc * 60 + +curr, 0);

var seconds1 = getSeconds(document.getElementById("stime").value);
var seconds2 = getSeconds(document.getElementById("etime").value);

var res = Math.abs(seconds2 - seconds1);

var hours = Math.floor(res / 3600);
var minutes = Math.floor(res % 3600 / 60);
var seconds = res % 60;

document.getElementById("time").value = seconds;
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="stime" class="form-control" required name="stime" type="time" value="12:00" />
    <label for="stime">Start Time</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="etime" class="form-control" required name="etime" type="time" value="12:30" />
    <label for="etime">End Time</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="time" class="form-control" name="time" type="text" />
    <label for="time">Time</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add context to your answer not just code. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is an answer. You can edit your question.